# Phrase or words to describe a diva/prima donna

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Good day,

I am looking for phrases or words to describe a diva, prima donna. Someone who is used to being spoilt, who does not like getting their proverbial hands dirty but instead just wants to be pampered and treated to fine wines, and first class jetsetting, shopping and 5 star hotels. Usually a woman who could never go camping or backpacking, outdoors, or ride in coach. Someone who is overly concerned about their appearance and their fashion.

What's the best way to describe a woman like this apart from diva/prima donna? Don't need a single word. Just effective way to articulate it.

Comment: Both *diva* and *prima donna* (but especially the latter) ***are*** words that have that meaning. What's wrong with them that you need something else?

Comment: I am hungry for more ways to communicate it.

Comment: You have provided lots of ways to describe them already!

Comment: Entitled and vain are the words that come to mind.

Comment: "A pain in the neck" or just "a pain"?

Comment: Sounds like a *spoiled brat*. One need not be young to be either spoiled or a brat.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two items:

1. ***Lady Muck***

*PHRASE*

*British informal*

A haughty or socially pretentious woman.

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lady_muck)

2. ***Princess***

*derogatory, informal*

A spoiled or arrogant young woman.

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/princess)

Comment: *Princess* may be as good as one can do in one word.

Comment: Your example illustrates the polysemy of this word.